# Probability of a maximal chain in a random subposet of a finite poset

Tags: pr.probability, posets, percolation

Let $P$ be a finite poset, and let $0<p<1$. Choose a random subposet
$Q$ of $P$ by letting each $t\in P$ belong to $Q$ with probability
$p$. What is the best way to compute the probability that $Q$ contains
a maximal chain of $P$? Are there good estimates (or even explicit
formulas) for well-known posets such as boolean algebras?

Comment: Doing some small Boolean algebras by hand, I get $p^2$ for the two element algebra,  $2p^3 - p^4$, and $p^8 + 6(1-p)p^7 + 15(1-p)^2p^6 + 18(1-p)^3p^5 + 6(1-p)^4p^4$, suggesting a dominant term in general (for smallish p) of $n!p^{n+1}$, unsurprisingly.  Gerhard "Don't Know About Largish P" Paseman, 2017.10.11.

Comment: Is it known in the case of a product of two chains? It has the flavor of percolation, but you’re computing the probability that two corners are connected, not two sides.

Comment: @SamHopkins: I don't know how to do it for the product  of two chains, but  I agree that it may be connected with percolation (which is why one of the tags is percolation).